# How do I get RestKit to format a date when using RubyMotion

Tags: date, restkit, rubymotion, formatter

I've setup a new RubyMotion project and have some JSON being mapped successfully to plain ruby objects. I'd like one of the attributes to be a date but I don't know how to get RestKit to do the conversion for me.

I know how to set the date formatters but how does RestKit know which attributes to apply the date formatters to? I assume when this is done in Objective-C the data type is inferred. 
Is there anyway to achieve this with ruby?

Model:

```
def SampleModel
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :created_at
end
```

Mapping:

```
def sample_mapping
  @sample_mapping ||= begin
    mapping = RKObjectMapping.mappingForClass(SampleModel)
    mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(["id", "name", "created_at"])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the property that a value is being mapped to is an `NSDate` then RestKit, when reading in, will apply each of the configured data formatters to the JSON until one of them returns a non-nil date object. When serialising only the `preferredDateFormatter` is used to generate the string from the date.

Comment: Yeah ok. So that's still my problem. Since ruby is dynamically typed, how can I specify that the :created_at attributes should be of type NSDate? I've updated the question to include some sample code. You can see there are no types specified.

Comment: Ah, I see, in that case it's a pure RubyMotion question about the class used to store attributes. If everything is `id` then an introspection based mapping will have issues...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a potential work around. It works but I wouldn't say it's a great solution.

Based on Clay Allsopp's article on [Mixing Objective-C and Ruby](http://clayallsopp.com/posts/mixing-objective-c-and-ruby/) I've created an Objective-C version of my model class in vendor/models and specified my NSDate attribute in there. The Ruby version of the model still exists so the rest of my model code stays in ruby. It doesn't even need to use inheritance to get the NSDate attribute. The ruby model class simply 're-opens' the class and adds additional attributes and behaviour.

**Code**

vendor/models/SampleModel.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SampleModel : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * created_at;

@end
```

vendor/models/SampleModel.m

```
#import "SampleModel.h"

@implementation SampleModel

  @synthesize created_at;

@end
```

Rakefile

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'
...

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  ...
  app.vendor_project('vendor/models', :static)
end
```

models/sample_model.rb

```
class SampleModel
  attr_accessor :id, :name
end
```

If anyone has a better solution I would love to hear it!

Thanks.